# Программа не выводит число

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int x; //Почему программа не выводит 42???/
  x = 42;
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`??/` является триграфом для экранирования перевода строки и при сборке с использованием С++ до С++17 (в котором триграфы убрали) строка x = 42 будет закомментирована, а программа будет содержать неопределенное поведение, так как `x` будет читаться неинициализированным.